# Loop through list of values in table

Tags: loops, foreach, stata

I have Stata code that starts with:

```
local MyState "[STATE ABBREVIATION]"
```

The user enters the state abbreviation (e.g., `"FL"`) and then runs the code. The rest of the code references `MyState` multiple times. For example:

```
keep if stateabb == `"`MyState'"' 
replace Goal = .95 if stateabb == `"`MyState'"'
save "Results for `MyState'.dta", replace
if (stateabb == `"`MyState'"' & pickone==1) using ...
```

I often have a list of 10 or so states for which I need this code run. It's saved in a table, called `"StatesToRun.dta,"` with one variable name, `"state"`.

Is there a way to edit my code so it loops through each state in my table, and runs the full code for each state?

I've studied the `foreach` and `forval` examples but cannot figure out how or if they would apply to this situation. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

`foreach` can take a local macro with a list of the states you want to loop through. The missing piece is actually creating this list. To do so, you can use `levelsof` with the `local` option on your "StatesToRun" dataset (not a 'table' in Stata terminology). *E.g.* (without testing):

```
use StatesToRun.dta, clear
levelsof state, local(statelist)

use data, clear
foreach MyState of local statelist {
    keep if stateabb == `"`MyState'"' 
    replace Goal = .95 if stateabb == `"`MyState'"'
    save "Results for `MyState'.dta", replace
    if (stateabb == `"`MyState'"' & pickone==1) using ... 
}
```

---

#### Postscript

However, unless you are generating "StatesToRun.dta" from another Stata do-file, it seems like it may be easier to simply define the list of states directly in the analysis do-file. The same basic method can be used:

```
local statelist MA NH VT ME CT RI PA NY 

use data, clear
foreach MyState of local statelist {
    keep if stateabb == `"`MyState'"' 
    replace Goal = .95 if stateabb == `"`MyState'"'
    save "Results for `MyState'.dta", replace
    if (stateabb == `"`MyState'"' & pickone==1) using ... 
}
```

If you want to define `statelist` and use it across multiple analysis do-files, see `help include` (note the difference between `include` and `do`): you can define `statelist` in a separate do-file and `include` it, rather than creating a Stata dataset with a single variable for the sole purpose of looping over the distinct values of this variable.

Comment: Perfect! I do need to use this same list of states with multiple .do files, so I went with the `use StatesToRun.dta, clear levelsof state, local(statelist)`. Works great. I tried to use `include` with a do-file but could not get the syntax right. As someone new to STATA, I find the help entries often lacking in detail and clarity. I tried creating a do file called `(states.do)` with this line: `local statelist AR CA CT`. I then added this line to one of .do files that need to call it: `include C:\MyData\states.do` but got a syntax error.